# How to download an ISO 8859-9 encoding XML file with node.js

Tags: node.js

for utf-8 encoded XML files there's no problem in using get method of http module. However when the encoding of the XML file is set to iso8859-9 , characters are not shown correctly. What could we do ?

```js
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var xpath = require('xpath');
var dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

var router = express.Router();

getXml = function(resUrl, callback) {
  http.get(resUrl, (res) => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    let data = '';

    // A chunk of data has been recieved.
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk.toString();
    });

    // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
    res.on('end', () => {
      callback(data);
    });
  }).end();
}
/* GET home page. */

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  getXml('http://server/xmlfile.xml', function(result) {
    var doc = new dom().parseFromString(result);
    var nodes = xpath.select("//person", doc);

    let str = '';
    nodes.forEach(element => {
      str += element.attributes.getNamedItem("name").value + "<br/>";
    });

    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Express' + str
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Kind regards

Comment: Please add your existing code that shows what you are already trying.

Comment: I added the code snippet, it's not so complicated, when I try to download an XML file with iso-8859-9 (?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-9"?) it doesn't show the characters correctly. Everyting is perfect for a utf-8 xml file.

Comment: If you know that the format is always 8859-9 then just set that as the encoding when you call `res.setEncoding('utf8');`. Offhand I don't know what value you would use in place of `'utf8'` but that should be fairly easy to find.

Comment: Setencoding method doesn't support iso8859-9 or any variation without dash or so as a parameter. It throws an exception. It seemed strange though

Answer (score 0):

```js
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var xpath = require('xpath');
var dom = require('xmldom').DOMParser;

var router = express.Router();

getXml = function(resUrl, callback) {
  http.get(resUrl, (res) => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    let data = '';

    // A chunk of data has been recieved.
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk.toString();
    });

    // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
    res.on('end', () => {
      callback(data);
    });
  }).end();
}
/* GET home page. */

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  getXml('http://server/xmlfile.xml', function(result) {
    var doc = new dom().parseFromString(result);
    var nodes = xpath.select("//person", doc);

    let str = '';
    nodes.forEach(element => {
      str += element.attributes.getNamedItem("name").value + "<br/>";
    });

    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Express' + str
    });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```